# Why does :command argument of make-process not work when string passed as a variable?

Tags: variables, process, call-process

This works fine:

`(make-process :name "my-proc2"
          :buffer " *my-proc2*"
          :command '("sh" "-c" "echo \"hi\"\nsleep 10\necho \"there\"")
          :connection-type 'pipe
          :filter (apply-partially 'my-pass-it-on-filter "/tmp/mytmprealtest"))`

But if I use a variable like the code below I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp body)`:

```
(let ((body "echo \"hi\"\nsleep 10\necho \"there from var\""))
  (make-process :name "my-proc2"
        :buffer " *my-proc2*"
        :command '("sh" "-c" body)
        :connection-type 'pipe
        :filter (apply-partially 'my-pass-it-on-filter "/tmp/mytmprealtest")))
```

The variable should be a string as well, so why doesn't it work?

The documentation for `make-process` says:

```
...
:command COMMAND -- COMMAND is a list starting with the program file
name, followed by strings to give to the program as arguments.
...
```

The variable was a string as were all other arguments, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You've *quoted* the list:

```
    :command '("sh" "-c" body)
```

So you have passed it a symbol `body` not the string value of the variable.

Try:

```
    :command (list "sh" "-c" body)
```

or:

```
    :command `("sh" "-c" ,body)
```

Either of which cause `body` to be *evaluated* to its string value.